# no-unused-expressions React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React and I am trying to run this code

```
    var animateButton = function(e) {
    
        e.preventDefault;
        //reset animation
        e.target.classList.remove('animate');
        
        e.target.classList.add('animate');
        setTimeout(function(){
          e.target.classList.remove('animate');
        },700);
      };
      
      var bubblyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("bubbly-button");
      
      for (var i = 0; i < bubblyButtons.length; i++) {
        bubblyButtons[i].addEventListener('click', animateButton, false);
      }
```

However, I am getting this error

`Line 3:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

I am not sure why I am getting this error, but I believe it is something related to React Framework

Answer (score 2):

The expression `e.preventDefault` doesn't do anything. You need to call the function: `e.preventDefault()`.